# Convert nested for loop in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am in new in programming.Can anyone please tell me how to convert this for loops in lambda expression

```
for (int num = 0; num < daysNew.Count(); num++)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < daysOld.Count(); count++)
    {
        if (daysOld[count] == daysNew[num])
        {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! We encourage users to show their work when asking a question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
bool isValid = !daysNew.Any(day => daysOld.Contains(day));
```

Comment: ok,i have a little confusion for performance i should use nested for loop or use lambda expression.

Comment: Linq exists for a reason. It makes code cleaner and more concise. You can see how 1 line of Linq code replaced 11 lines of your code (and eliminated 1 bug). It does have some overhead, but this shouldn't be an issue unless your program is performance critical. So I would advise using the Linq approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use List.Any() method to loop as:

```
bool isValid = !daysNew.Any(day => daysOld.Contains(day));
```

or

```
bool isValid = !daysOld.Any(day => daysNew.Contains(day));
```

It will check in "daysOld" for each element for each element in "daysNew"

Comment: `Any()` is an `IEnumerable` method. If you want a real `List` method, use `Exists()`. Same results without type conversion.